Is there a way to abort httpRequestBegin pipeline in controller?
My manager insisted there is a way to abort the custom item resolver pipeline component inside a controller after the controller failed to find an item from a search service.
I do not think it is possible because the httpRequestBegin pipelines are already executed before controller logic. But to be safe I would like to get a confirmation before I can confidently make such statement to my manager.
Thank you!

You are correct in your assumption that you cannot abort the httpBeginRequest pipeline in a controller. But you can achieve what you want to do by moving the logic to find an item from the controller into the item resolving part of the httpBeginRequest pipeline. This is a standard way to handle wildcards and make sure that you can handle 404's correctly.

Thank you! inside our controller, we have a code to looking for video/id, are you suggesting that we move the logic of resolving the video into item resolver by checking the pattern of video/* ... if not found from there we can abort the pipeline so it would go to next redirect pipeline? our redirect processor would check if the video id id1 has been replaced by id2, if so we wanted to redirect to id2
